# Causal diagram for difference-in-difference case-control study

Tags: difference-in-difference, confounding, pre-post-comparison, causal-diagram

I'm working on a matched cohorts difference-in-differences healthcare study with the following causal diagram:

[image]

where $X$ is the binary (Yes/No) nurse intervention identifying the treatment and control cohorts, $Y_1$ is pre-period outcome, $Y_2$ is post-period outcome (both measuring # inpatient visits), and $\Delta Y$ is the change score $Y_2 - Y_1$. Therefore, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ have a deterministic (not random) relationship with $\Delta Y$.

Based on this diagram, $Y_1$ is a confounder and $Y_2$ a mediator that is excluded, hence the final model should control on $Y_1$ and $X$ with $\Delta Y$ as the outcome.

But this is the same as simply regressing $Y_2$ on $Y_1$ and $X$ correct? So a difference-in-difference analysis is not necessary.

Comment: Do you really mean that the baseline $Y_1$ *causes* $X$?

Comment: How is this a "matched" design? Do you, rather, mean that it's a pre/post design and each subject has a baseline value $Y_1$, some subjects receive an intervention $X$ and then you observe the follow-up $Y_2$?

Comment: @AdamO Yes, that's correct. To clarify, we're using exact & propensity score matching on selected variables in our study to control for confounding.

Comment: How can you use *both* matching types? Also how does $Y_1$ cause $X$? Adding the $\Delta Y$ as a variable does not make sense since it's structurally related to $Y_1$ and $Y_2$. The point of difference-in-difference analyses is that you are WLOG trying to predict the "post" response,

Comment: @AdamO Exact + propensity score matching is frequently used to balance covariate distributions in treatment and control groups - we're exact matching on a subset of variables that have primary importance or are moderators, then propensity score match on the remaining variables. $Y_1$ causes $X$ because our nurse's home visits (i.e., participation in the "treatment" group) are triggered by a subject's inpatient event. No, we're not predicting the post response as an end, rather we're attempting to find an unbiased estimate of the treatment effect on average post - pre scores.

Comment: @AdamO As far as the validity of adding variables with deterministic relations to the causal diagram, that's a good question & is a good topic for another post. I'm reading Judea Pearl and he has no qualms with adding $Y_1$, $Y_2$, and $\Delta Y$ to causal diagrams when discussing Lord's Paradox. However Laura Hatfield only includes $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ in her diagrams (see https://diff.healthpolicydatascience.org/).